# Passing arguments to a function and calling it via "&"

Tags: elixir

Is there any way to shorten these kinds of method calls:

```
aaa = Enum.find(Statuses, fn(x) -> x.name == :pending end)
```

to something like this:

```
aaa = Enum.find(Statuses, &==, [:name, :pending])
```

That is, to pass the arithmetic operator "==", structure field name `name` and value `:pending` as arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [partial application syntax](http://elixir-lang.org/crash-course.html#partials-and-function-captures-in-elixir) for this:

```
aaa = Enum.find(Statuses, &(&1.name == :pending))
```

or

```
aaa = Enum.find(Statuses, & &1.name == :pending)
```

```
iex(1)> f = &(&1.name == :pending)
#Function<6.52032458/1 in :erl_eval.expr/5>
iex(2)> f.(%{name: :pending})
true
iex(3)> f.(%{name: :complete})
false
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, the answer by Dogbert is perfect, as usual, I would put mine here too, for the sake of formatting.

This is a perfect example of when Elixir “prevents” you from doing things in a wrong way. If there is *no* such method on hand, it pretty much means the approach is wrong.

You are looking for a struct, that has a `name` having value `:pending`. Do that explicitly, with [`Kernel.match?/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#match?/2) macro:

```
iex> [%{n: 1, name: :pending}, %{n: 2, name: :complete}]
     |> Enum.find(&match?(%{name: :pending}, &1))
%{n: 1, name: :pending}
```

---

Quote from the documentation:

> [`match?/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#match?/2) is very useful when filtering of finding a value in an enumerable:
>
> ```
> list = [{:a, 1}, {:b, 2}, {:a, 3}]
> Enum.filter list, &match?({:a, _}, &1)
> #⇒ [{:a, 1}, {:a, 3}]
> ```

Comment: Unfortunately this is incorrect: `[%{n: 1, name: :complete}, %{n: 2, name: :pending}] |> Enum.find(&%{name: :pending} = &1) #=> ** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: %{n: 1, name: :complete}`.

Comment: @Dogbert indeed, but this looks silly to me. It should probably work (maybe  not that exact way, but with some other `Enum.select/2` or like method.) I will remove this answer, and fullfil a feature request instead.